# calculate the sum of values in a column in jTable netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to calculate the sum of values of a column in a jTable and assign it into a jTextField.

```
double s=0;

DefaultTableModel tableModel=(DefaultTableModel) jTable33.getModel();

for(int i=0;i<jTable33.getRowCount();i++){
    String d= tableModel.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
    double d1=Double.parseDouble(d);
    s+=d1;
}

String c=jTextField66.getText().toString();
double cout=Double.parseDouble(c);
s=s+cout;
```

The jTextField only gets the value of cout !
Please help me solving this.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on here. 1. Why are you calling `toString()` on String? 2. You wrote that you want to assign something to JTextField, but I don't see `jTextField.setText()` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've deleted this line: `DefaultTableModel tableModel=(DefaultTableModel) jTable33.getModel();` and changed the for loop a little t:

```
for(int i=0;i<jTable33.getRowCount();i++){
            String d= jTable33.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
            double d1=Double.parseDouble(d);
            s+=d1;
}
```

and it goes just fine.
I recommend you to read this [JTable tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and check the API. Good luck.